# Sequelize Unable to update associated record after object creation

Tags: express, sequelize.js

I am running into an issue where I can't seem to reveal my newly created record ("organization"), take a value from that record ("organization.organizationId") and then apply that value when updating a record's value ("user.organizationId") in another table. I see the SQL commands for `INSERT INTO` and `UPDATE`, but no value is found in the UPDATE. It doesn't make sense to me because `console.log(organization);` reveals the object like so:

```
{ dataValues: 
   { organizationId: 18,
     organizationName: 'sdfsafnuffd',
     admin: 'jdofsdjf@mfsdfa.com',
     members: 'jdofsdjf@mfsdfa.com',
     updatedAt: Mon Jan 11 2016 21:07:44 GMT-0500 (EST),
     createdAt: Mon Jan 11 2016 21:07:44 GMT-0500 (EST) },
```

Here are the SQL commands from my route:

INSERT INTO:

```
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `organization` (`organization_id`,`organization_name`,`admin`,`members`,`updatedAt`,`createdAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,'sdfsafnuffd','jdofsdjf@mfsdfa.com','jdofsdjf@mfsdfa.com','2016-01-12 02:07:44','2016-01-12 02:07:44');
```

UPDATE:

```
Executing (default): UPDATE `user` SET `updatedAt`='2016-01-12 02:07:44' WHERE `user_id` = 18
```

**organization.js model:**

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

var Organization = sequelize.define('organization', {
    organizationId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        field: 'organization_id',
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    organizationName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        field: 'organization_name'
    },
    admin: DataTypes.STRING,
    members: DataTypes.STRING
},{
    freezeTableName: true,
    classMethods: {
        associate: function(db) {
            Organization.hasMany(db.User, {foreignKey: 'user_id'});
        },
    },
});

    return Organization;
}
```

**user.js model:**

```
var bcrypt   = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

var User = sequelize.define('user', {
    user_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    firstName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        field: 'first_name'
    },
    lastName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        field: 'last_name'
    },
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        isEmail: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    organizationId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        field: 'organization_id',
        allowNull: true
    }
}, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    classMethods: {
        associate: function(db) {
            User.belongsTo(db.Organization)
        },
        generateHash: function(password) {
            return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
        },
    },
    instanceMethods: {
        validPassword: function(password) {
            return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
        },
    },


});
    return User;
}
```

db-index.js setup:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var path = require('path');
var config = require(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..','./config/config.js'));
var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, {
    host:'localhost',
    port:'3306',
    dialect: 'mysql'
});

sequelize.authenticate().then(function(err) {
    if (!!err) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to the database:', err)
    } else {
        console.log('Connection has been established successfully.')
    }
});

var db = {}

db.Organization = sequelize.import(__dirname + "/organization");

db.User = sequelize.import(__dirname + "/user");
db.Organization.associate(db);


db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

sequelize.sync();

module.exports = db;
```

**route:**

```
var express = require('express');
var appRoutes   = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var localStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var models = require('../models/db-index');

appRoutes.route('/sign-up/organization')

    .get(function(req, res){
        models.User.find({
            where: {
                user_id: req.user.email
            }, attributes: [ 'user_id', 'email'
            ]
        }).then(function(user){
            res.render('pages/app/sign-up-organization.hbs',{
                user: req.user
            });
        })

    })

    .post(function(req, res, user){
        models.Organization.create({
            organizationName: req.body.organizationName,
            admin: req.body.admin,
            members: req.user.email
        }).then(function(organization){
            console.log(organization);
            models.User.update({
                annotationId: organization.organizationId
            },{ where: { user_id: req.user.user_id }});
            res.redirect('/app');
        }).catch(function(error){
            res.send(error);
            console.log('Error at Post' + error);
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
models.User.update({
            annotationId: organization.organizationId
        },{ where: { user_id: req.user.user_id }});
```

Not sure if this is a type-o or not, but annotationId doesn't seem to be defined in your model.

Comment: Wow, good catch. Dumb mistake. Thanks for catching that. Issue resolved!